# what is the different between oslo.config and oslo_config?

Tags: python, oslo

I`m trying to use the oslo config package. But I found that someone is using this package like this

`import oslo.config`

while some others using it like this

`import oslo_config`

I`m confused , can anyone tell me what is the difference between this two package? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The oslo namespace package is deprecated, you can see nothing in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist_packages/oslo`, except middle directory, after `oslo.config` is installed. so use `oslo_config` instead when you want to import something.